# Nodejs Session Maintanience

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Are there any existing Session management libraries for node.js? I'm looking for something that can do password authentication for a user (using MongoDB as backend) and maintain the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions. The most prominent of which is most likely [`Passport.js`](http://passportjs.org/). It supports basic password authentication, as well as oAuth based authentication strategies for a variety of sites. It can also serialize users into the session easily, and can be used as [Express](http://expressjs.com/) middleware.

Passport's biggest competitor currently seems to be [`EveryAuth`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/everyauth), which also supports password authentication, but seems to be more focused on oAuth-based solutions. Both of these play excellently with MongoDB, and the sessions can be persistent, depending on how they're stored. (Memory Stored sessions will be cleared on Reboots, while Redis/MongoDB sessions will persist. [Redis is probably the best, since it's a fast key-value store, comparable to the speed of memory access]).

If you're looking at how to manage the session itself, there's [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#readme), which used to be bundled with Express, or available as a standalone library, and is perfect for handling [sessions](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.There is a library called passport.js(Its got social auth,local auth and session maintainence) http://passportjs.org/